# Run without debugging in VSCode automatically changes terminal

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, gnu-screen

I am trying to run my current python file through Visual Studio Code.

- I have a default 'bash' terminal and from there, I create a 'screen'.
- I click on the 'Run without debugging' option in VSCode and expect the code to run inside 'screen'.
- However, the terminal automatically switches to 'Python Debug Console' and runs from there.

May I know if there is any way to run the code on the 'screen' terminal itself?

Answer (score 0):

Currently in VS Code, the debugging function of python code is provided by the "Python" extension. Therefore, it uses the "Python Debug Console" by default and does not support custom debugging terminals.

But you could customize the terminal for running python code,
For example, for windows, please change the path of the executable terminal in the setting `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":`.

Reference: [Integrated Terminal in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode the shortcut to run a script is Ctrl+Shift+P.
[Shows the options in VSCode when Ctrl+Shift+P is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lISi3.png)
In this option choose the "Run Python file in Terminal", it should run correctly.
The default terminal in case of window is Command Prompt.

You can change it in the setting using the Ctrl+, short cut and going to terminal.external.windowsExec settings. Here the path to executable of the shell is shown.